# snap vs apt install (here for eclipse)

Tags: apt, 18.04, eclipse, snap

When calling `eclipse` in terminal I am told to do one of

```
sudo snap install eclipse         
sudo apt  install eclipse-platform
```

However `snap search eclipse` gives only

```
Name       Version  Developer     Notes    Summary
eclipse    4.7.3a   snapcrafters  classic  Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE
mosquitto  1.5      ralight       -        Eclipse Mosquitto MQTT broker
```

whereas `apt search eclipse` gives a huge list of eclipse related packages. Does this mean that if I want to have e.g. "Python IDE for Eclipse" I have to go for the apt variant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's compare version numbers.

1. Official Ubuntu repository has [`eclipse` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eclipse&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=bionic&section=all) with **3.8.1** version.
2. Snap - [Eclipse **4.7.3a**](https://uappexplorer.com/snap/ubuntu/eclipse) (as you have already discovered, should be installed with `snap install eclipse --classic`)
3. [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) has **4.7.3a**:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
   umake ide eclipse
   ```

Snap version has access to removable media because of `--classic` confinement:

> This revision of snap "eclipse" was published using classic confinement
>   and thus may perform arbitrary system changes outside of the security
>   sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which may put your system 
>   at risk.

But I recommend version from Ubuntu Make. It is more straightforward.

Comment: So that would mean for python development "ubuntu make" and "pycharm" instead of "eclipse" and "pydev". Right?

Comment: Right, or [`eclipse-pydev` 3.9.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=eclipse-pydev&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=bionic&section=all) from APT-repository. I have never used Eclipse for Python development. I tried Spyder3, it works great.

Comment: Clarification: doesn't `classic` confinement means it acts like usual `.deb` package, which has access to system?

Comment: The Eclipse snap is indeed classic confined, so has access to the entire system, including external USB or other mounted filesystems.

Comment: @popey in the Eclipse case you are right. Because of `--classic` nature it works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: TIL Ubuntu Make