# (solved) Can't start (snap version of) Thunderbird - error "Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: thunderbird

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Thunderbird was working fine until this morning when I received some Ubuntu updates.
Since then, even after reboot, Thunderbird doesn't work anymore : When I launch it nothing happens (it works like if it's going to open but doesn't open).
No error message visible but the journal indicates "Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
And I can see the thunderbird-bin is using 105mo in my RAM even after the failed loading period is over.

I've tried a "sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module" but the issue is still here, even after reboot.

I've tried to contact the thunderbird support BUT it requires to send an email to validate the account created, and of course I can't read my emails with thunderbird not working.

I've got to add that I'm using a snap version of Thunderbird 78.12.0.

If there is no better solution, I wonder how it's possible to uninstall/reinstall a snap version of Thunderbird (or auto repair it). If you know please let me know.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to load module “canberra-gtk-module” .... but already installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I've tried the various solutions on the link you indicated but that doesn't solved my issue.

Comment: thunderbird as snap? why not from ubuntu sources?

Comment: To be honest I'm an Ubuntu Noob so I've just probably google searched 'how to install Thunderbird" and typed the commands of the first result. 
Do you think I can uninstall the snap version and replace it with the normal one without loosing emails or appointments ?

Comment: I've tried (after backup of the .thunderbird folder) to uninstall the snap thunderbird and re-install it ... but issue still here.
But then I've solved the issue by uninstall the snap thunderbird and install the normal version (from the Ubuntu software store) and this time it worked (after having copied the backup in the new .thunderbird folder).
And now everything works great again and I haven't lost anything !  :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [snap vs apt install (here for eclipse)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040341/snap-vs-apt-install-here-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by uninstall the snap thunderbird and install the normal version (from the Ubuntu software store) and this time it worked (after having copied the backup I made of the old .thunderbird folder in the new .thunderbird folder).
Now everything works great again and I haven't lost anything ! :-)